# Set data in a tabular format on jbuttons

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans, jbutton

[image: Table under which jbuttons to be displayed]

I have to display data on a jbutton which is retrieved from a database(mysql) but due to different length of the strings involved the presentation looks bad and disordered. Is there a way to get the alignment.This is my code to set the data on the jbutton 'j' is the jbutton array

```
  j[check].setText(rs.getString(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getString(3)+"  "+rs.getString(4)+" "+ws+rs.getString(5)+" "+rs.getString(6)+" "+rs.getString(7));
```

I have given some spaces for some particular set of data but in most cases it goes bad.

Here are 2 cases in which the lengths are different

```
CSE201 Programming Fundamentals 3 Saritha V. SJT-401 A1 59
CSE201 Programming Fundamentals 3 Yokesh Babu SJT-402 A1 58
```

Now after the 3rd string(i.e after "CSE201 Programming Fundamentals 3") the lengths differ and formatting goes bad.

Comment: @sola if i give no spaces then the formatting would go even worse as some strings have a length of 10 and some may go upto 25.

Comment: Could you please add an example of the desired output?  I suspect you want to modify the strings so that they have the same length?

Comment: @ViktorSeifert i have made the edit and i think if i make their lengths equal then it would work

Comment: Uhm I find this really suspect why are you displaying such lines of text on `JButtons`?? Surely a `JTable` will do? You can retrieve selected/clicked cells etc as needed

Comment: @DavidKroukamp i used tabbed spaces and had uloaded the same but an edit was made.

Comment: @HarshitSharaff I see, well as I said JButton not ment for that

Comment: @DavidKroukamp ya i didnt work?

Comment: @HarshitSharaff: I still don't see why `JTable` wouldn't work, as @David suggests.

Answer (score 2):

As kleopatra comments, you need to chose your [desired layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Absent a clear statement of what you mean by *bad and disordered*, consider these alternatives:

- `FlowLayout`, the default for `JPanel`, will use the enclosed component's preferred size.
- `GridLayout` will ensure that the enclosed components are the same size and large enough to accommodate the largest button. An example is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3420431/230513) for a grid of `JPanel` instances each containing a `JButton`; note that the buttons are centered by default. As you want a single row with an arbitrary number of columns, use `new GridLayout(1, 0)`.
- `BoxLayout` with `LINE_AXIS` will attempt to use the preferred width of the enclosed components, as shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html).

Be sure to `pack()` the enclosing `Window`. If this is not helpful , please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits any problem(s) you encounter.

Comment: Also consider `JToolBar`, illustrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11949899/230513).

Comment: By bad and disordered i mean that the look and feel.Also the method you suggest would only order size of my buttons but the text in it differs.

Comment: A button's preferred size is calculated by the UI delegate based on the size of the name in pixels. If you change the name at run-time, you can `validate()` the enclosing `Container` to recalculate the sizes and `repaint()` to refresh the display.