# java thread and jtabbedpane

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jtabbedpane

i'm developing an application in java to "monitor" trains interruptions.

In fact, i'm reading log.txt files and showing them into a JTabbedPane with differents panes which correspond to differents cities.

There is a main GUI with a JPane and i'm inserting a JTabbedPane in this using a Thread, and in this JTabbedPane, i'm inserting panes using threads.
I'm doing this way because i want to update panes (with log files infos) every minutes without blocking all the GUI.
Is this the right way to do a monitoring app?

My problem is when i have created all tabs i wanted, i can't update them, when i try to update one, it's always the last one that is updated.

Here is my code :
Creating new JTabbedPane

```
Controller.Controller_ListeOnglets n = new Controller.Controller_ListeOnglets(View.View_Application.getJPanel());
    n.start();
```

Here is the way i add tab in JTabbedPane

```
public class Controller_ListeOnglets extends Thread {

    JPanel jo = new JPanel();

    public Controller_ListeOnglets(JPanel j) {
        jo = j;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        View.View_ListeOnglets t = new View.View_ListeOnglets();
        jo.add(t);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list = Controller_Modification.ChercherSystemes();
        for (String i : list) {
            try {
                Controller_Onglet nouveau = new Controller_Onglet(View.View_ListeOnglets.getJTabbedPane(), Controller.Controller_BDD.GetSystemeID(i));
                nouveau.start();
                this.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException | SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Controller_ListeOnglets.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }


    }
}



  public class Controller_Onglet extends Thread {

        Model.Model_Systeme systemeB;
        static JTabbedPane jo = new JTabbedPane();

        public Controller_Onglet(JTabbedPane j, Model.Model_Systeme systemeA) {
            jo = j;
            systemeB = systemeA;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            View.View_Onglet onglet = new View.View_Onglet(systemeB);
            if (jo.getTabCount() == 0) {
                jo.add(onglet);
                jo.setTitleAt(jo.getTabCount() - 1, systemeB.getSysteme_Nom());
                jo.setBackgroundAt(0, Color.CYAN);


            } else {
                jo.add(onglet, jo.getTabCount());
                jo.setTitleAt(jo.getTabCount() - 1, systemeB.getSysteme_Nom());
                jo.setBackgroundAt(jo.getTabCount() - 1, Color.CYAN);

            }
            /* Timer t = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {

             @Override
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {*/
            if (EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
                Controller_TraitementFichier traitement = new Controller_TraitementFichier(jo, systemeB.getSysteme_Nom());
                traitement.start();
            } else {
                Controller_TraitementFichier traitement = new Controller_TraitementFichier(jo, systemeB.getSysteme_Nom());
                traitement.start();
            }
            /*}
             });
             t.start();*/


        }
        //A ComplÃ©ter

        public static void removeOnglet(Model.Model_Systeme systeme) {
            for (int i = 0; i < jo.getTabCount(); i++) {
                if (jo.getTitleAt(i).equals(systeme.getSysteme_Nom())) {
                    jo.remove(i);
                }
            }

        }
```

And this is an example of how i'm trying to update a Tab

```
public class Controller_TraitementFichier extends Thread {

    String title = null;
    JTabbedPane jo = null;

    public Controller_TraitementFichier(JTabbedPane j, String titleOnglet) {
        title = titleOnglet;
        jo = j;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {



        InputStream flux = null;
        try {
            flux = new FileInputStream("./src/Ressources/Archivage_LISATEL/12203005.TXT");
            InputStreamReader lecture = new InputStreamReader(flux);
            BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(lecture);
            String ligne = buff.readLine();
            try {
                while (ligne != null) {
                    View_Onglet onglet = View_ListeOnglets.getJTabbedPane(title);
                    if (title.equals(title)) {
                        View.View_ListeOnglets.getJTabbedPane().setSelectedIndex(0);
                        onglet.changeTexteArea1(ligne + "\n");
                        jo.setBackgroundAt(View.View_ListeOnglets.getJTabbedPane().getTabPlacement(), Color.red);
                    }

                    ligne = buff.readLine();
                }
                System.out.println("Traitement " + title);
                buff.close();
                lecture.close();
                flux.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Controller_TraitementFichier.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            //System.out.println(View.View_ListeOnglets.getJTabbedPane().getTitleAt(View_ListeOnglets.getJTabbedPane().getSelectedIndex()));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Controller_TraitementFichier.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        } finally {
            try {
                flux.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Controller_TraitementFichier.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it's not really clear so if you want to help me more, i'll send you my code.

Thanks

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SwingWorker`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513), to query data in the background and update the GUI on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). Each tab's content can have it's own [worker thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

Comment: Thank you, i changed my code and SwingWorker is working but i can't update a specific tab, it's always the last one which is updated.
I mean, in every tab i got a JTextArea and i want to set different text in the different tab, but how can i do that?

Comment: You might compare your code with this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11949899/230513) or use it to create an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

All Swing changes must be performed in AWT Event Thread. To make your code correct you should implement all your Swing updates in a separate Runnable object and call these updates using SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable);

Something like this:

```
public class DataCollector implements Runnable {
  public void run() {
   // collect data
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
       // do swing update
     }
   });
  }
}
```

Other possibility is using of SwingWorker class.