# Java PropertyResolutionException when binding netbeans combobox selected item

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jcombobox

I have a `JComboBox` which I designed in the Netbeans GUI designer. I have successfully bound the "elements" of the box to an `ArrayList<String>` so that the box populates properly. However, it currently automatically displays the first element of the list as the `selectedItem`.

I tried to bind the `selectedItem` to an `int` at first, thinking it would just show the item at the indicated index. No go. I got a ginormous exception that I didn't understand.

Then, I noticed that in the "Binding" window, it said the element had to be an `Object`. So, I bound it to a `String`, thinking that it would find the element that matched that string and show that element. No dice. Now I'm getting some sort of "`PropertyResolutionException`". I've even tried to use an Integer object with the same result.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Absent your [sscce](http://sscce.org/), it's hard to say where things have gone awry. For reference, [`setSelectedItem()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setSelectedItem%28java.lang.Object%29) works as advertised in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11949899/230513) that selects L&F by name.

[image]