# Making the first and last JList item highlight squared

Tags: java, swing, jlist, nimbus

I'm using the Nimbus look and feel. When I have a JList and I select the first or the last item the highlight is rounded. Normally it's a square shape.

[image]

How do I change it to square as the other elements?

Comment: I can' se that, plase whats JDK & Native OS

Comment: for better hep sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about `JFrame` with `JList` in `JScrollPane`

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11949899/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had accidentally changed the BorderFactory to use Line Border with rounded corners. After removing this the cells appeared correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own [`ListCellRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) giving it the visualation you like.