# How to fit a JPanel into a JTabbedPane size?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm trying to add a `JPanel` into another and to fit it to the parent `JPanel size.

I have a `JPanel` which contains a `JTable` and a `JButton` using this code:

```
JScrollPane attributeTable = new JScrollPane(this);

JPanel attributesPanel = new JPanel();

JPanel textFieldPanel=new JPanel();
JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();

JButton newAttributeButton = new JButton("New Attribute");

attributesPanel.add(textFieldPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
attributesPanel.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

newAttributeButton.addActionListener(AttributesTableController.getInstance());

GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(textFieldPanel);
textFieldPanel.setLayout(layout);

// Turn on automatically adding gaps between components
layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);

// Turn on automatically creating gaps between components that touch
// the edge of the container and the container.
layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

// Create a sequential group for the horizontal axis.

GroupLayout.SequentialGroup hGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup();

// The sequential group in turn contains two parallel groups.
// One parallel group contains the labels, the other the text fields.
// Putting the labels in a parallel group along the horizontal axis
// positions them at the same x location.
//
// Variable indentation is used to reinforce the level of grouping.
hGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup().
         addComponent(attributeTable).addComponent(newAttributeButton));
layout.setHorizontalGroup(hGroup);

// Create a sequential group for the vertical axis.
GroupLayout.SequentialGroup vGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup();
vGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE).addComponent(attributeTable));
vGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.CENTER).
         addComponent(newAttributeButton));
layout.setVerticalGroup(vGroup);
```

When I had this panel (named `attributesPanel`) into a tab of a `JTabbedPane`, it just display the `JTable` and the `JButton`, but in the center of the panel. I would like that the dimension of `attributesPanel` are the same as the dimension of opened tab.

This is the code I use to add the JPanel into my JTabbedPane:

```
TabbedPane tabbedPane = new TabbedPane();
tabbedPane.setComponentAt(1, attributesPanel);
```

I tried using a `GridLayout`, it fitted the `JPanel` well but I was not able to resize the button. I tried with a `FlowLayout` and a `GridBagLayout`, but I was not able to display them correctly because I had the same problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11949899/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is incomplete sop it is hard to tell what is wrong, but maybe this will help:

```
JTable table = new JTable (12, 5);
JButton button = new JButton ("Button");

JPanel panel = new JPanel ();
panel.setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
panel.add (table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
panel.add (button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane ();
tabbedPane.addTab ("Tab", panel);

JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.getContentPane ().setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
frame.getContentPane ().add (tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.pack ();
frame.setVisible (true);
```