# Tabs are collapsed

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I am creating a GUI where the main window will contain a number of tabs. They should be positioned next to each other horizontally.

Using this code makes a "collapsed" version, where I can toggle the tabs with the arrows.

```
    JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
    JPanel tab_virksomheder = new JPanel();
    tabs.addTab("Virksomheder", tab_virksomheder);

    JPanel tab_praktikpladser = new JPanel();
    tabs.addTab("Praktikpladser", tab_praktikpladser);

    panel.add(tabs);
```

How can I make the tabs stand next to each other?

[image]

Comment: Read the JTabbedPane API and follow the link to the Swing tutorial on "How to Use Tabbed Panes" for a working example.

Answer (score 2):

The `panel` container should have a layout set like `BorderLayout` for instance.

```
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Answer (score 1):

The exact result depends on several things:

- The platform's TabbedPaneUI, `AquaTabbedPaneUI` on Mac OS X.
- The setting supplied to `setTabLayoutPolicy()`.
- The preferred size of the content, used when `pack()` is invoked on the enclosing `Window`.

You can use this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11949899/230513) to experiment with various Look&Feel settings. Note how the content's preferred size defines the size of each tab's content pane.

[image]