# How to append users message to a separate JTextPane using smack

Tags: java, swing, chat, smack

I'm new to the smack API i created a chat programe with it, which seems to be very well successful, i used a JTabbed pane that adds a JSplitPane which also adds a textArea where client types in message and a JTextPane that inserts received message. but the problem is that each time a message is received it appends to both JTAbbedPane that holds a textPane. what i actually want is each JTabbedPane/JtextPAne should be independent to itself...each chat with a user should be seen on a particular tabb not all tabs.....

Comment: <b>please i need this to work!!! the project is to be reviewed this week</b>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are adding the *same* content to each tab. Instead, create a *different* instance of your chat container for each tab, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11949899/230513). Two approaches are common:

- Extend `JPanel` and establish instance variables for any required objects.
- Create a factory method, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11949899/230513). Use `getClientProperty()` and `putClientProperty()` to store and retrieve any required objects.

Comment: yes i'm adding the same content to each tab.... i'm actually adding the JsplitPane that holds content for the chat!!!,.... buh with a distinct user

Comment: You are welcome. Am I correct to infer that each user also need their on instance(s) of `Smack` library classes that communicate with the chat server?

Comment: Yes!!! Thanks TrashGod.... Sorry I'm replying late... but it was successful.