# Adding ChartPanel to JTabbedPane using JPanel

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart, jtabbedpane, chartpanel

I want to add `JFreeChart` to `JPanel` and then add `JPanel` to `JTabbedPane`. I managed to display `JFreeChart` on `JFrame`, but I want to add `JFreeChart` as a 4th tab of `JTabbedPane`.

Code to display Chart:

```
public class Chart extends javax.swing.JPanel {

  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        JPanel jPanel1 = new JPanel();
        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        dataset.setValue(60, "Marks", "Student 1");
        dataset.setValue(40, "Marks", "Student 2");
        dataset.setValue(90, "Marks", "Student 3");
        dataset.setValue(50, "Marks", "Student 4");
        dataset.setValue(70, "Marks", "Student 5");
        dataset.setValue(30, "Marks", "Student 6");

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
            "Student Marks", "Student Name", "Marks", dataset,
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);
        CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot();
        p.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.BLACK);
        ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        panel.setDomainZoomable(true);
        jPanel1.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));

  }
```

Code to add to TabbedPane:

```
tabStoreTrans.add("chart", new Chart());
```

Comment: Have you tried `setComponentAt()`? Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits any problem you encounter.

Comment: @trashgod thnx for your reply. I used above coding to add JPanel to JTabbedPane. But it didnt show up the chart. Im using JfreeChart first time today. Thnx i ll try with setCOmponenAt() method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As shown in [*How to Use Tabbed Panes*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html), you can add components to a tabbed pane. `ChartPanel`, a subclass of `JPanel`, is such a component. In addition to [these examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html#eg), you can use the example below to experiment with other features.

As you are new, [limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513) using the NetBeans GUI editor, implied in your question, but continue to use the NetBeans IDE.

[image: tabbed charts]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15715096/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11949899/230513
 */
public class TabChart {

    private static final int N = 128;
    private static final Random random = new Random();
    private int n = 1;

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("TabChart");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();
        jtp.add(String.valueOf(n), createPane());
        f.add(jtp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        p.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Add") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jtp.add(String.valueOf(++n), createPane());
                jtp.setSelectedIndex(n - 1);
            }
        }));
        f.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private ChartPanel createPane() {
        final XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Data");
        for (int i = 0; i < random.nextInt(N) + N / 2; i++) {
            series.add(i, random.nextGaussian());
        }
        XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
        new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                series.add(series.getItemCount(), random.nextGaussian());
            }
        }).start();
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Test", "Domain",
            "Range", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, false, false);
        return new ChartPanel(chart) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(480, 240);
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TabChart().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I managed to solve my problem using this code. thnx