# JfreeChart not displaying before a click

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have built an display a TabPanel. At this stage no Chart is displayed .When I click on a button, I build a new chart an add it to the panel. But nothing happens. I have to click on the panel to have the chart displayed at last.

So I put a repaint() on the TabPanel which contains the ChartPanel but with no effect. Am I missing something here ?

```
        if(myChart==null){
            myChart = new PortfolioChart(portfolioModel.getDataMatrix());
            add(myChart.createPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            repaint();
        }else{
            myChart.setPortfolio(portfolioModel.getDataMatrix());
            myChart.updateDataSet();

        }
```

May be I should put the repaint() instruction on something differrent ?

Comment: Sometimes invalidate(); repaint(); works. Also try to invoke those methods to the ChartPanel if it still does not work

Comment: Also double check if you're doing this from the EDT.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still does not work for me.

Comment: The only solution that I found, which is dirty and weird, is to simulate an update of the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

In the complete example shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15715096/230513), each tab has a `ChartPanel`. Rather than *replacing* the chart, each chart's data model is *updated* periodically, and the listening chart repaints itself in response.

[image]

Comment: My construction is nearly the same as yours... but, I only add a chart when the button is pushed. In your algorithm, all the charts are built before the Pack() instruction. The problem is probably there.

Comment: My "Add" button adds a new chart after `pack()` when the button is pushed; you should't have to `revalidate()`.