# How to update a chart dynamically using JFreeChart?

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I am trying to generate a chart dynamically that will show the value change over time. I am storing those value in an `ArrayList< Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>` and retrieving those values in this class. But it doesn't show the addition of the values in that `ArrayList` over time.

Here actually another two thread is updating that `ArrayList` and I need to show the values of that `Arraylist` in a chart that will be dynamic.

The below is the code based on this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15715096/230513):

```
package com.model.presentation;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
//import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
//import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;

import com.model.resources.Household;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15715096/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11949899/230513
 */

public class DisplayChart {

    //private static final int N = 128;
    //private static final Random random = new Random();
    private int n = 1;
    static int count = 0;

    public void display() 
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Community Rescilience Model");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();
        jtp.add(String.valueOf(n), createPane());
        f.add(jtp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        p.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Add") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jtp.add(String.valueOf(++n), createPane());
                jtp.setSelectedIndex(n - 1);
            }
        }));
        f.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private ChartPanel createPane() 
    {
        final DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

        final String name = "Community ";

       /* for (int i = 0; i < random.nextInt(N) + N / 2; i++) 
        {

            while (iterator.hasNext()) 
            {
                Map.Entry map = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
                String community_name =  name + String.valueOf(map.getKey());
                ArrayList<Integer> dataArrayList = (ArrayList<Integer>) map.getValue();
                for (Iterator<Integer> it = dataArrayList.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
                {
                    dataset.addValue(it.next(), community_name, String.valueOf(count));
                    count++;
                }
            }
         }*/
       // XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
        new Timer(100, new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                Iterator<Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>> iterator = Household.goods.entrySet()
                        .iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) 
                {
                    Map.Entry map = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
                    String community_name =  name + String.valueOf(map.getKey());
                    ArrayList<Integer> dataArrayList = (ArrayList<Integer>) map.getValue();
                    for (Iterator<Integer> it = dataArrayList.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
                    {
                        dataset.setValue(it.next(), community_name, String.valueOf(count));
                        count++;
                    }
                 }
                }

         }).start();
        JFreeChart lineChart = ChartFactory.createLineChart("Resource Production/Consumption over time", "Time",
                "Number of GOODS", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                true, true, false);
        return new ChartPanel(lineChart) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() 
            {
                return new Dimension(1000, 500);
            }
        };
    }


    /*public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DisplayChart().display();
            }
        });
    }
}*/

}
```

The main class is :

```
public class Main_class {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new DisplayChart().display();
        }
    });
}
```

This code works but at certain point, it gets stuck. It means it does not show the value of the changes in that `Arraylist`.

Comment: Possible [duplicte](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15707496/230513).

Answer (score 1):

I have it running indefinitely although i am not sure it is still working as you intended.

I didn't have the Household class so I just faked it with.

```
class Household {
    static public Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> goods = new HashMap<>();
}
```

I also don't think I have your code for adding data to the plot. I did it like this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
while (true) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            final int fi = i;
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ArrayList<Integer> l = Household.goods.get(fi);
                    if (l == null) {
                        l = new ArrayList<>();
                    }
                    l.add(rand.nextInt(100));
                    if (l.size() > 20) {
                        l.remove(0);
                    }
                    Household.goods.put(fi, l);
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    }
}
```

Note that it is important to do it in the EventQueue thread or you will get a ConcurrentModificationException.

The real issue seems to be that your adding the same data in the list over and over again associated with different counts.

So I changed:

```
    for (Iterator<Integer> it = dataArrayList.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
    {
           dataset.setValue(it.next(), community_name, String.valueOf(count));
           count++;
     }
```

To :

```
for (count = 0; count < dataArrayList.size(); count++) {
    dataset.setValue(dataArrayList.get(count), community_name, String.valueOf(count));
}
```

Comment: For reference, the complete original program is seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15715096/230513).