# Positioning a button in java swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

[image]

Hello,

How can I move the button "Apply" in the right of that bottom panel without "absolute layout?

Comment: Learn and use the layout managers. And also nest JPanels. The main JPanel should use BorderLayout. A bottom JPanel should be placed into the main JPanel's BorderLayout.PAGE_END location. The bottom JPanel can also use BorderLayout, and then add the button can be added BorderLayout.LINE_END.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Doesn't the default `JPanel` (`JFrame.getContentPane()`) already have a `BorderLayout` by default?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire: yes it does.

Comment: Thanks! It works with group layout at the second jPanel..first one is border Layout.

Answer (score 3):

Specify `FlowLayout.RIGHT` for the panel holding the button, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15715096/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513):

```
JPanel p = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
```

Then add `p` to the `SOUTH` or `PAGE_END` area of a panel having `BorderLayout`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was very useful :D