# Java Look and Feel Installation : Installed List of LaFs is not updated

Tags: java, swing

I want to try out the scores of look and feels easily.

I made an app with a JList that lists installed Look and Feels using

`UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo[] lafInfo = UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels();`

and it sets the selected look and feel using

`UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lafInfo[i].getClassName());`
`SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(owner);`

`owner.pack();`

However the Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\ext\seaglasslookandfeel-0.2.jar is not listed!

How do you install all looks and feel INSIDE the Java system so that it is returned by 
UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels(); ?

EDIT: Right now I'm using this hack. But I don't like it because it is not pluggable.
For every single LaF, I run this code at the start of the application

```
 try {
     String look = "com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel";
     Class.forName(look);
     UIManager.installLookAndFeel("Sea Glass", look);
  }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
  }
```

Comment: Can you try this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11949899/230513)?

Comment: thx for the link. it was helpful but not in answering my question. here my issue 1) how do you install 20+ new Lafs without modifying any of your code