# Java Swing - makeTextPanel() method for tabbedpane

Tags: java, swing

Where is this method from? I've tried looking for it and i cant find it. The only example i've seen it used in was where JPanel is extended and it is called in the constructor. The problem is i do not want to extend JPanel so how do i go about creating an object(my question is what class) so that i can access this method? I don't know where JPanel inherited this method from.

```
JComponent panel1 = makeTextPanel("Panel");
tabs.addTab("Display", panel1);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11949899/230513).

Comment: It's actually contained within the demo from the page you've linked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is from here: [`TabbedPaneDemo.java`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TabbedPaneDemoProject/src/components/TabbedPaneDemo.java) which can be found under the heading: ***"Code for Tabbed Panes"*** on that [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html).

```
protected Component makeTextPanel(String text) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(false);
    JLabel filler = new JLabel(text);
    filler.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    panel.add(filler);
    return panel;
}
```

You don't have to extend anything. You can make it `static`.

Comment: OH! I totally missed that. Thank you.

Comment: I find those tutorials very hard to navigate personally. Things become easily missed.