# How to change tabs location in JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtabbedpane

I want to change tabs location from left to center. How can I do this? I think I must change Look&Feel, but I don't know how.

From this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Comment: I can explain you how to change the single component UI and what you need to override in your case, but to provide the centered tabs you will probably need to invest some days.

Comment: Don't know how to change the Look & Feel or don't know how to extend `BasicTabbedPaneUI`?

Comment: @CatalinaIsland I mean I don't know what property in Look&Feel need to change the centering tabs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already pointed out, you have to use an LookAndFeel which supports this design (centered Tab-Button).
When your selected LaF does not support this, you have to write your own **TabbedPaneUI.**
(But this may not be very easy.)

If you do not want to create your own TabbedPaneUI, you have to look for an existing custom TabbedPaneUI or TabbedPane-Component, which support this kind of layout.

You can take a look at this article, to get started:
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072927/swing-gui-programmingloseandmaxtabbedpane--an-enha/swing-gui-programming/closeandmaxtabbedpane--an-enhanced-jtabbedpane.html

Answer (score 1):

The placement of tabs is determined by the `JTabbedPane` UI delegate, typically based on [`BasicTabbedPaneUI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicTabbedPaneUI.html). Not every Look & Feel implementation supports centered tabs, so there's no property that will work by default across platforms.

As a concrete example, `com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel` supports centered tabs, as shown below. The class `com.apple.laf.AquaTabbedPaneUI`, which implements the effect, is shown [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/macosx/classes/com/apple/laf/AquaTabbedPaneUI.java).

Because the implementation is non-trivial, a better choice is to support the user's Look & Feel choice using [`Preferences`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/index.html). A suitable Look & Feel selection control is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11949899/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/230513).

[image]

The source for the example above is seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11949899/230513).