# What is meant by "indirect composition patterns"?

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns

From Wikipedia (and some other sources):

> Swing's heavy reliance on runtime mechanisms and indirect composition
>   patterns allows it to respond at run time to fundamental changes in
>   its settings.

Google failed me. What is this "indirect composition pattern"? And what makes it "indirect"?

Comment: [Look and Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) is the most pervasive such feature, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11949899/230513).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that author of this statement mean, that Swing is injecting dependencies (composition) underneath (indirect, user doesn't have to know about it happening) and can do it at runtime.